# What's the meaning of the output of cv2.calcHist?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, histogram

I'm using the function  `cv2.calcHist` and using all the channels of RGB with:

`hist1 = cv2.calcHist([image1], [0, 1, 2], None, [8, 8, 8],[0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])`

I can't understand the output of this function... Can someone please help understand?

```
import PIL
images = [ PIL.Image.open(f) for f in glob('blur_data/*') ]

def img2array(im):
    if im.mode != 'RGB':
        im = im.convert(mode='RGB')
    return np.fromstring(im.tobytes(), dtype='uint8').reshape((im.size[1], im.size[0], 3))

np_images = [ img2array(im) for im in images ]
image1 = np_images[0]
hist1 = cv2.calcHist([image1], [0, 1, 2], None, [8, 8, 8],[0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
print hist1

>>
    [[[  2.30000000e+01   8.90000000e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  3.00000000e+00   1.61600000e+03   3.10000000e+01   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   7.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]

     [[  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  2.20000000e+01   6.64600000e+03   4.33900000e+03   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   5.53000000e+02   3.34100000e+03   1.94000000e+02
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   2.60000000e+01   8.00000000e+01
         2.20000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]

     [[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   3.20000000e+02   1.60500000e+03   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   1.01500000e+03   3.08020000e+04   2.69100000e+03
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   8.00000000e+01   1.57660000e+04   6.86400000e+03
         1.31000000e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   5.00000000e+00   1.33500000e+03
         2.00000000e+02   8.60000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   1.27000000e+02   3.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]

     [[  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   3.40000000e+01   2.14700000e+03   1.00000000e+02
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   1.16000000e+02   6.30100000e+03   2.86500000e+03
         1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   1.30000000e+01   3.51800000e+03   1.53400000e+04
         3.92900000e+03   3.40000000e+01   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.70000000e+01   3.01200000e+03
         3.16900000e+03   2.79000000e+02   2.40000000e+01   1.50000000e+01]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         5.19000000e+02   3.90000000e+02   1.29000000e+02   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.99000000e+02   3.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]]

     [[  0.00000000e+00   7.00000000e+00   3.50000000e+01   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   1.40000000e+01   5.44700000e+03   9.24000000e+02
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.33400000e+03   1.20150000e+04
         8.82000000e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.78000000e+02   4.69600000e+03
         2.86400000e+03   1.80000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.35700000e+03
         4.05900000e+03   4.09000000e+02   9.00000000e+00   1.50000000e+01]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.02000000e+02
         1.70200000e+03   2.53000000e+03   4.76000000e+02   1.60000000e+01]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         1.31000000e+03   3.34300000e+03   2.82000000e+02   3.52000000e+02]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.91000000e+02]]

     [[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   4.63200000e+03   5.25200000e+03
         0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
      [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   6.50000000e+01   1.45970000e+04
     3.94000000e+03   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   6.06000000e+02
     3.47800000e+03   5.60000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.49000000e+02
     2.10100000e+03   5.14000000e+02   1.00000000e+01   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   7.00000000e+00
     1.68100000e+03   2.39600000e+03   5.56000000e+02   1.70000000e+01]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     5.12000000e+02   5.09300000e+03   8.28000000e+02   3.79000000e+02]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     0.00000000e+00   1.82300000e+03   5.22900000e+03   1.10700000e+03]]

 [[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.99000000e+02   7.71600000e+03
     0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.43930000e+04
     7.64800000e+03   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.69000000e+02
     7.85000000e+02   8.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   2.00000000e+01
     1.16000000e+02   3.20000000e+01   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     5.35000000e+02   4.31000000e+02   1.39000000e+02   1.30000000e+01]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     5.86000000e+02   1.30600000e+03   1.16900000e+03   5.65000000e+02]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     0.00000000e+00   8.64000000e+02   1.17400000e+03   5.90000000e+02]]

 [[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.50000000e+03
     0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   8.66700000e+03
     2.32430000e+04   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     3.33800000e+03   2.07000000e+02   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     3.00000000e+01   2.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   3.10000000e+01
     5.76000000e+02   4.77000000e+02   1.56000000e+02   1.90000000e+01]
  [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
     3.70000000e+01   4.92000000e+02   1.82900000e+03   4.15200000e+03]]]
```

Comment: Try this: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: My point is what is the output when using all 3 channels at same time. All other examples are using only one channel or one Channel per graph. @ZdaR

Comment: 3 channels each range from 0 to 255 (let's say a BGR image) means for example in bin (0,0,0) you have the number of pixels which had pixel value (0,0,0). bin (0,255,0) counts the number of green pixel (value 0,255,0) and so on.

Comment: What's the return type?  np.ndarray or list?